# Split string to maximum length and append the rest to the last array item

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for me to split a string into an array and limit to `x` and if there are more parts than the limit append to the last array item?

So, for example I have

```
'Billy Bob Joe'.split(' ', 2) // Outputs ["Billy", "Bob"]
```

I would like to output

```
["Billy", "Bob Joe"]
```

Is there a way for this to be easily done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice` and `join` like:

```js
function customSplit(str, splitter, max) {
    let res = str.split(splitter);
    if(max < res.length)
        res.push(res.splice(max - 1).join(splitter));
    return res;
}


console.log(customSplit('Billy Bob Joe', ' ', 2));
console.log(customSplit('a b c d e f g h', ' ', 4));
```

Comment: I came up with something similar using `split`, `shift` and `join`

Comment: Since you use `splitter` to join, you lose the ability to use regexes as `splitter`s

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (run code snippet to see result):

```js
var base_str = 'Billy Bob Joe whatever';

//try here limit 1 , 2, 3 and see console.log result
var base_split = base_str.split(' ',2);

var second_str = base_split.join(' ');

var second_split = base_str.split(second_str);

base_split.push(second_split[1].trim());

console.log(base_split);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, but it's not super optimized

```js
function explode(del, str, limit) {
  let items = str.split(del), r = []
  for(let i = 0; i < limit - 1; i++){ r.push(items.shift()) }
  r.push(items.join(' '))
  return r
}

console.log(explode(' ', 'Billy Bob Joe', 2));
console.log(explode(' ', 'a b c d e f g h', 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will create a regex string matching the number of words passed as an argument.

```js
  const buildRegexString = function(numWords) {
      let regexStr = '^'
      for (let i = 1; i < numWords; i++) {
          regexStr += '(\\S+)\\s';
      }
      regexStr += '(.*)';
  
      return regexStr;
}


 const input = 'Billy Bob Joe Ringo George';
 const regex = new RegExp(buildRegexString(3));

 const match = input.match(regex);
 const result = match.slice(1);

 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do that using split function
you can use

```
var str = "Billy Bob Joe";
var res = str.split(" ",1);
str=str.replace(res,'');
```

Now str have Bob Joe